# Origin of japanese metasyntactic variables 「ほげ」

Tags: etymology, programming

[Metasyntactic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable) are using in programming as placeholders.
Wikipedia mentions several Japanese words used in this fashion, and I would like to know how they came about.

- [ほげ - hoge](https://jisho.org/word/%EF%BD%88%EF%BD%8F%EF%BD%87%EF%BD%85)
- [ぴよ - piyo](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%B4%E3%82%88)
- [ふが - fuga](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%B5%E3%81%8C)
- [ほげら - hogera](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%BB%E3%81%92%E3%82%89)
- [ほげほげ - hogehoge](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%BB%E3%81%92%E3%81%BB%E3%81%92)*

*this one seems obvious; it just repeats the first word twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's one I can't find much about, but I think I've determined the basis for most of your list.  Here it is, regrouped a bit:

> - ほげ - hoge
> - ほげら - hogera
> - ほげほげ - hogehoge
> - ふが - fuga
> - ぴよ - piyo

The first three are all variations on *hoge*.  Digging around, this appears to derive from the verb *hogeru*, "a hole opens up, a hole appears; to fall apart".  Since the metasyntactic variable is really a *place*holder, or a kind of stop*gap* for the actual variable to be used in the programmer's own code, this *hoge* is a "hole" for the programmer to fill.  Alternatively, since the "hole" meaning might be archaic or dialectal, this might arise instead from the "fall apart" sense as a sort of [calque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque) of the English metasyntactic variables *foo* and *bar*, presumably from [*fubar*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fubar) in reference to things having "fallen apart" (rather dramatically).

*Hoge**ra*** would then be *hoge* + suffix *-ra*, often used as a pluralizer or generalizer (as in *kochi**ra***, *soko**ra**-hen*, etc.).

*Hogehoge*, as you noted, is just *hoge* reduplicated.

- See also [the Weblio entry for ほげ](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BB%E3%81%92), [the Weblio entry for ほげる](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BB%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B), and [the Kotobank entry for ほげる](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%BB%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B-383338).

*Fuga*, meanwhile, looks like half of *fugafuga*, "blathering, spluttering".  As a generic term of "something that doesn't have any particular meaning of its own", this makes sense to use as a metasyntactic variable name.

- See [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B5%E3%81%8C%E3%81%B5%E3%81%8C) and [Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%B5%E3%81%8C%E3%81%B5%E3%81%8C-616787) for ふがふが.

Lastly, *piyo* only shows up, as far as I can tell, in *piyopiyo* as an [onomatopoeia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/onomatopoeia#English) for the sound of chicks chirping or tweeting.  This might be used in a similar fashion as *fuga*, as "something that doesn't have any particular meaning of its own".

- See [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B4%E3%82%88%E3%81%B4%E3%82%88) and [Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%B4%E3%82%88%E3%81%B4%E3%82%88-613682) for ぴよぴよ.

That said, the above is only my best guess based on the minimal research I've done to date.  I haven't found a source that clearly states, "this metasyntactic variable name comes from XYZ..." for any of the above.  The Japanese Wikipedia article on メタ構文変数 [explicitly mentions *hoge* and *piyo*](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BF%E6%A7%8B%E6%96%87%E5%A4%89%E6%95%B0#hoge%E3%81%A8piyo), but about their origins, it only states that 「起【き】源【げん】は定【さだ】かではない」 ("the origins aren't certain").